# Restructuring an object with map and forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, lodash

I've got an object that i'm trying to map to a react component (using lodash). The current shape of the objects that I get back from my API (firebase) looks like this...

```
// ex. 1
{
  "-Kdkahgiencls0dnh": {
    "name": "a name",
    "desc": "a description",
    "other": "some other guff"
  },
  "-Ksdfadfvcls0dsnh": {
    "name": "another name",
    "desc": "another description",
    "other": "some more"
  },
  "-kgoandiencls0dnh": {
    "name": "I am a name",
    "desc": "I am a description",
    "other": "I am some other guff"
  }
}
```

...but, I loose the primary key when i run through `_.map()`

What i'm trying to do is get my object in the shape of:

```
// ex. 2
[
  {
    "id": "-Kdkahgiencls0dnh",
    "name": "a name",
    "desc": "a description",
    "other": "some other guff"
  },
  {... the next object ...},
  {... etc ...}
]
```

What i'm doing now is getting my data in the `componentWillMount` lifecycle method like so:

```
componentWillMount() {
  firebaseRef.on('value', snap => {
    let data = snap.val() // the whole original object (see ex. 1)
    let tempArray = [] // an array to store my newly formatted objects
    _.forEach(data, (item, key) => {
      // Here's where i'm not really sure what to do.
      // I want to use Object.assign to set a new key:value
      // That adds "id": "-theobjectsmainkey" to a new object
      // then push to my tempArray and finally setState with the
      // correctly formatted array of objects.
    })
  })
}
```

Ideas? Thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()`, `.map()` and object spread

```js
const data = {
  "-Kdkahgiencls0dnh": {
    "name": "a name",
    "desc": "a description",
    "other": "some other guff"
  },
  "-Ksdfadfvcls0dsnh": {
    "name": "another name",
    "desc": "another description",
    "other": "some more"
  },
  "-kgoandiencls0dnh": {
    "name": "I am a name",
    "desc": "I am a description",
    "other": "I am some other guff"
  }
}

let res = Object.entries(data).map(([id, prop]) => ({id, ...prop}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: YAS!!! This is exactly what i was after. I wish i had a better grasp what this was doing...

Comment: @archae0pteryx See [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator),

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind you will need a polyfill for `Object.entries`.  A more traditional approach would be to iterate the object using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: @aaaaaa Polyfills are available, where needed, and linked at comment above.

Comment: @guest271314 - a developer who does it for a living and not necessarily because they enjoy it typically doesn't think of browser compatibility.  They copy paste the answer and only find out via a bug report that it breaks.  You didn't explicitly warn about nor link the polyfill.

Comment: @aaaaaa _"a developer who does it for a living and not necessarily because they enjoy it typically doesn't think of browser compatibility. They copy paste the answer and only find out via a bug report that it breaks. You didn't explicitly warn about nor link the polyfill."_ ? Any developer, whether they develop as a career or for a hobby had best not simply "copy paste". That is simply lazy conduct. Read the documentations and test the procedure before you deploy anything.

Comment: @guest271314 - you must not work with junior developers

Comment: @aaaaaa Do not work with lazy individuals of any kind in whatever field may be engaged in for that particular project. They can go home if they are so incompetent as to "copy paste" code; or any other similar activity, if engaged in a different theater of industry. "junior" or tenured does not matter. Lazy is lazy.

Comment: @guest271314 - must be nice, but in reality we have lazy people consuming SO and browser incompatibility is a major oversight by them.

Comment: @aaaaaa "Nice" has nothing to do with it. Not here to be be nice, nor foster a "nice" work environment during a project. Here to learn and share. There to do a job. That is their problem if the "copy paste" without reading documentations. It is this users issue if post incorrect answers, which will promptly delete, here, if realize the code or description is inaccurate.

Answer (score 3):

Lodash's `_.map()` callback receives as a 2nd parameter the iterated key. Use object assign, to create a new object with the key as id:

```
const array = _.map(data, (item, id) => Object.assign({ id }, item))
```

**Demo:**

```js
const data = {"-Kdkahgiencls0dnh":{"name":"a name","desc":"a description","other":"some other guff"},"-Ksdfadfvcls0dsnh":{"name":"another name","desc":"another description","other":"some more"},"-kgoandiencls0dnh":{"name":"I am a name","desc":"I am a description","other":"I am some other guff"}};

const array = _.map(data, (item, id) => Object.assign({ id }, item));

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Personally I don't like how lodash's flavor of `map` takes a collection and outputs an array, but this behavior is exactly what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
componentWillMount() {
  firebaseRef.on('value', snap => {
    let data = snap.val() // the whole original object (see ex. 1)
    let tempArray = Object.keys(data).map((item, key) => {
        return {
            "id": item,
            "name": data[item].name // etc, a structure what you want
            ...
        };
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: The first example gives: ```[
  {
    "desc": "First description",
    "subtitle": "First subtitle",
    "title": "First Project Title"
  },
  {
    "desc": "No need for a description here. Nothing to see",
    "subtitle": "Subtitle of the gods",
    "title": "Another Project"
  },
  {
    "desc": "If i had a desc it would go here",
    "subtitle": "I am subtitle hear me roar",
    "title": "Final project example"
  }
]```

Comment: This does not add the id property

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, using only pure JS :

```
const raw = {
  "-Kdkahgiencls0dnh": {
    "name": "a name",
    "desc": "a description",
    "other": "some other guff"
  },
  "-Ksdfadfvcls0dsnh": {
    "name": "another name",
    "desc": "another description",
    "other": "some more"
  },
  "-kgoandiencls0dnh": {
    "name": "I am a name",
    "desc": "I am a description",
    "other": "I am some other guff"
  }
}

let formatted = Object.keys(raw).map(
  key=>Object.assign(raw[key], {"id": ""+key})
);
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Voltra/Lo5nrb25/) to get a live demo.